# File .profile is not sourced on Debian Buster (testing)

Tags: bash, debian, .profile

I added a few things to my PATH variable in .profile on a  fresh install of Debian Buster, but inspecting the environment on reboot, I see that nothing changed. What could be the problem?

The added line is:

```
PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH
```

On further inspection, it only does not get sourced if I login through a graphical login. Logging into a virtual console sources everything properly.

Comment: [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/360134/108618) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/633642/693277) may advance your research a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `.profile` is sourced by a login shell.

It seems the terminal windows created by your graphical system don't create login shells. If you use `bash` as your shell, you can either have them started as `bash -login` to source `.profile`, or you can put your commands in `.bashrc'.

If you use another shell, consult the documentation.

Comment: I use Debian from ca 2002. During all those years I've been working with various graphical systems and they have all been creating a login shell. The only change from the usual way I set up my Debian system is that I have XFCE alongside Gnome and Fluxbox. The login manager is the default Debian login manager. Also, I have noticed that when I "su" the /usr/sbin is not in the PATH. This means that evne /etc/profile was not sourced. I think something either changed in how the system boots (systemd?), or my setup is somehow botched.

Comment: The command `su` doesn't create a login shell, while `su -i` does. The login manager doesn't matter, what matters is how the shell in your terminal is started.

Comment: Turns out that lightdm, the default display manager, did not initialise using .profile, or /etc/profile. Got rid of it and installed good old xdm. Now all works.

Answer (score 2):

I use Debian Buster with Mate, and for that in the mate console mark the option "Run command as a login shell" to load the variables from the file .profile